# How should the php array look like for this json output when using json_encode()?

Tags: php, json

I want a json output to look like this;

```
[{ title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
{ title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2" }]
```

I have decided to use php's json_encode() to produce this json output. But I am puzzled how should the input array to json_encode look like to produce this json output?

Thank you.

Comment: The json output isn't valid. When you do a decode you will only get the information in the first object. All the answers are correct if you had [] brackets around this.

Comment: Thanks. I made the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = array(
   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 1", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 1"),
   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 2", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 2")
);

json_encode($input);
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NqpNSI)

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw That is exactly the reason you're able to edit other's answers.

Comment: @Marty ... yes, but, it is just a very small typo

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw What I mean is that for small typos in an otherwise correct answer, the edit feature should be used :-)

Comment: Not exactly sure how I put a 0 in json heh, maybe I got abducted by 4l13ns. Edit: Oh, somebody edited my post with it I see :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the items like this:

`$arrayItem = array( "title" => "Dynamic Title1", "content" => "Dynamic content1" )`

If you want an array that have the items, you can add them to the array like this:

`$array = array();
 $array[] = $arrayItem;`

And then encode the entire array or the `$arrayItem` separately if it's your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_encode` method of PHP, it returns the JSON representation of a value

```
$phparray = array(
        array("title"=>"Dynamic Title 1", "content"=>"Dynamic content 1"),
        array("title"=>"Dynamic Title 2", "content"=>"Dynamic content 2")
    );    
// You can simply get the JSON string like this
$json = json_encode($phparray);

// OR if your php version is >= 5.4.0
$json = json_encode($phparray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Ref:** [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)